# How to fix my dynamic drop down. It won't fire up

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to implement a dynamic drop-down select for country-city for my search project. I am having difficulties in my codes to run. I only get errors.

I have some codes for Controller, Java and HTML codes. Loading of Country from the database works fine but its does not load the cities owned by a  country.

Model

```php
    namespace App;
    use App\Listings;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Cities extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'newcitymun';
        protected $fillable = ['citymunDesc'];
        public $timestamps = false;
        public static function getCitymunInfo($id) 
        { 
            return Citymun::find($id);
        }
    }
```

Controller

```php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Location extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'location';
        protected $fillable = ['location_name'];
        public $timestamps = false;  
    }
```

Index

```
    <select id="location" name="location" class="form-control">
        <option value="">{{ __('messages.select_location') }}</option>
        @foreach(\App\Location::orderBy('location_name')->get() as $location) 
            <option value="{{$location->id}}">{{$location->location_name}}</option> 
        @endforeach 
    </select>


    <select id="citymun" name="citymun" class="form-control">
        <option value="">{{ __('messages.select_location') }}</option>
        @foreach(\App\Citymun::orderBy('citymunDesc')->get() as $citymun) 
        <option value="{{$citymun->id}}">{{$citymun->citymunDesc}}</option> 
        @endforeach 
    </select>
```

Javascript

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $("#location").change(function(){
          var loc=$("#location").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
        url: "{{ URL::to('ajax_citymun') }}/"+loc,

        success: function(result){

        $("#citymun").html(result);
           }
        });                
        });
    });
    </script>
```

citymun php

```
    <option value="">.. select city ..</option>
    @foreach($citymun as $i => $citymun)                                  
      <option value="{{$citymun->id}}">{{$citymun->citymunDesc}}</option>                                                  
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Please add the errors that you get. It helps us to help you.

Comment: Make sure you have APP_DEBUG set to true in you .env. So you can get a proper error screen.

Comment: i have no error but it does'nt fire up the city drop down.